# JavaScript functional programming - is it bad from a garbage collection standpoint?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Writing JavaScript with the functional programming style means that we treat the objects as immutables. Does that mean it will produce a lot more garbage? In particular, they often allocate a large number of short-lived objects on the heap.

I wonder if there are any research or blog posts on how functional programming impacts performance from a garbage collection standpoint?

Comment: V8 uses a generational garbage collector. So short-lived objects are reclaimed quickly.

Comment: https://deepu.tech/memory-management-in-v8/

Comment: @Barmar I tried to google the term generational garbage collector but cannot seem to find any useful info about it. Could you give me the link to the definition?

Comment: Did you read the section on GC in the link I gave?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Generational_GC_(ephemeral_GC)